How to effective pre-process / prepare a large codebase for RAG using a local LLM?
I want to use RAG on our organisation's codebase using a local Open-source LLM? How can i prepare the files of codebase to work with RAG.
I tried converting all the files of the codebase to txt files and fed into LLM, but I dont think its the best approach.

I would suggest using code parsers that are available for free and then chunking off those parsed code. Then it's simple RAG after that. Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) parsers are one of the most famous in the market to do code parsing. Just know that parsing text and parsing code is different. Finding context from the code is done by parsing it effectively according to class and functions and many more.
